# Would it be possible to have a w3c community? - w3c.stackoverflow.com

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-proposal

I was just at a W3C meeting last night and realized that a Stack Exchange community might just be the type of community that this standards body needs.

How do the other community sites (English Language and Usage, Drupal, Wordpress) get started?

Comment: It seems too small an audience for a SE site, but if the W3C wants a Q&A platform, I'm guessing SE Inc would love to help. But a W3C.SE without official backing from W3C doesn't really seem viable.

Comment: You should email them and ask.

Comment: Why does it need to be separate from Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our usual process for creating sites is through Area 51. (As [amanaP lanaC A nalP A naM A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155556/amanap-lanac-a-nalp-a-nam-a) [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133646/166017), always check that there isn't already an active proposal for the topic you're suggesting, please!.)

As [BoltClock said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133645/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-w3c-community-w3c-stackoverflow-com#comment371112_133645), if you have a special scenario, send an email with all of the details to team@stackoverflow.com (there's a "contact us" link in the footer of every page on the network). We do consider exceptions to our usual processes from time to time, but - being exceptions and all - they're judged on a case by case basis. In this case, if the W3C as an organization is endorsing and committed to the idea of a W3C Stack Exchange site, definitely shoot us an email to start a conversation.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether Stack Exchange's Area 51 can really work for smaller expert communities. The process (very rightly) is more geared at the participation of a large number of people, including a number of high-rep users from the existing network. A W3C proposal (as in, a site where the *actual W3 consortium*  asks questions, exchanges information, and to a lesser extent discusses problems while working on new standards) is unlikely to gain the necessary size.

Also, you have very little control over how the site's features work and develop - this may turn out to be a problem e.g. if the site is used for specific voting procedures.

You may be better off using one of the [SO clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones).

Of course, that way, you're responsible for installing, polishing, customizing, and maintaining the platform, which can be quite a bit of work.

Another option might be talking to SE, Inc. about a stand-alone copy of the SO engine. They are said to be offering this to companies for in-house use for very large sums of money. Maybe the W3C can get a discount, or a fully sponsored solution, or some other form of co-operation.

Comment: The W3C is not small at all.

Comment: @Bolt but is it big enough to form a site that, eventually, will grow into something big enough to support itself? I'm not sure. I think it would need a special cooperation between the consortium and SE, Inc. to make sure it takes off, and doesn't die at some point of the Area 51 process...

Answer (score 3):

What good would such a site be? If it's about the use of W3C standards (HTML, XML, CSS, XSLT, etc), then that's pretty much covered by Stack Overflow and/or Programmers.SE. We get questions on these topics *all the time*.

So if it's not about the use of W3C standards, then what would it be about? If it's for the W3C members themselves... they don't need it. Stack Exchange is designed for Q&A: real questions, which produce real answers. W3C members don't need a Q&A site; they need a place to *discuss* things. And the SE kinda sucks at discussing anything (which is the *point*: it inhibits discussion by sucking at it).

And anyway, W3C members already have discussions. Via e-mail and private/public mailing lists. Why do they need an SE site on top of that?

Comment: Mailing lists work fine for some kinds of interactions, but they aren't particularly participatory.  It's not as easy to jump into a thread & pursue just one small issue (as it is here).

I'd also say that in defining best practices, that it is very much like a QA process.  What is the best practice for say accessible modal dialogue interfaces?

Comment: @MikeGifford: "I'd also say that in defining best practices, that it is very much like a QA process." How? *Defining* best practices (as opposed to someone simply telling you what the already defined practices are) is something that requires *discussion*. Back and forth between people with different perspectives and viewpoints. An e-mail exchange or forum would be far better than trying to use the comment system in SE or something.

Comment: @MikeGifford: "they aren't particularly participatory" Which is kinda the point. If you're not willing to sign up for a free mailing list, then your input probably isn't that important anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and propose a new site.

But first make sure a that it has not been proposed already!

Comment: Just by searching Area 51 for the same topic?